# Using mathsf in a section title

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, sectioning, errors

I'm trying to use the mathsf font in a section title and it wont compile.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{verbatim, rotating, stmaryrd, bbm, pict2e, ytableau, mathrsfs, amssymb, mathtools}

\newcommand{\Dsg}[1]{{\mathsf{D}^b_\mathsf{sg}(#1)}}
\newcommand{\APC}[1]{{\underline{\mathsf{APC}}(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$\APC{S} \simeq \Dsg{S}$}

hi

\end{document}
```

It works without the table of contents tag, but with it when I compile this I get an error:

```
Latex Error: ./temp.toc:1 \mathsf allowed only in math mode.
```

The ./temp.toc file consists of just one line:

```
\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{${\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {\mathsf {APC}}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax (S)} \simeq {\mathsf {D}^b_\mathsf {sg}(S)}$}}{1}
```

I'm not sure how to parse that to figure out what's wrong.  Why can't I use \mathsf in math mode in a section title?

Comment: The problem isn't `\mathsf` but `\underline`. This should work: `\newcommand{\APC}[1]{{\protect\underline{\mathsf{APC}}(#1)}}`. Or `\DeclareRobustCommand{\APC}[1]{{\underline{\mathsf{APC}}(#1)}}`

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, thanks!  I don't actually know what ``\protect`` does, is there a short explanation of why ``\underline`` was causing problems and ``\protect`` fixes it?

Comment: When section titles are written to the `.toc` file expandable macros get expanded. Sometimes this breaks things like in this case. `\protect` prevents the unwanted expansion (actually it does something else and very clever... :) Defining `\APS` as a robust command prevents its expansion in such contexts (through something similarly clever) so `\underline` doesn't even get to be expanded then.

Comment: See: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collecting the comments into an answer:

The problem isn't `\mathsf` but `\underline`.  The latter is a fragile command and those frequently pose problems in moving arguments such as section titles.

Here are two definitions that should work:

- `\newcommand{\APC}[1]{{\protect\underline{\mathsf{APC}}(#1)}}` or
- `\DeclareRobustCommand{\APC}[1]{{\underline{\mathsf{APC}}(#1)}}`

When section titles are written to the `.toc` file expandable macros get expanded. Sometimes this breaks things like in this case. `\protect` prevents the unwanted expansion. Defining `\APS` as a robust command (kind of) prevents its expansion in such contexts so `\underline` doesn't even get to be expanded then. More details on this can for instance be found in [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)